# Idle timer within Vue Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, timer

I am have some issues resetting my timer when no longer idle.  I am using `Vue Idle` for this, which is a wrapper for `idle.js`.

So I have a modal with the id timeout-modal.  When Vue Idle triggers the idle function, I call `showWarningMessage`.

Within this function, I first display my modal.  I then create a timer which my modal uses to do a countdown.  So this all works fine.

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                timerId: 0,
                remainingTimeoutSeconds: 10000
            }
        },
        computed: {
            second() {
                return this.remainingTimeoutSeconds / 1000;
            }
        },
        onIdle () {
            this.showWarningMessage();
        },
        methods: {
            showWarningMessage() {
                this.$bvModal.show('timeout-modal');
                this.warning = true;

                 this.timerId = setInterval(() => {
                    this.remainingTimeoutSeconds -= 1000;
                }, 1000);
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now within the modal there is a continue button.  When pressed, it should basically reset the above timer.  At the moment I have

```
handleContinueButtonClick(response) {
    if (response.data.success) {
        console.log("IN")
        this.$bvModal.hide('app-timeout-reminder-modal');
        clearInterval(this.timerId);
        return;
    }
}
```

So what this should do is hide the modal, and then reset the timer back to 10 seconds.  It is entering the above as the console is printing `IN`.  The modal is also
hidden when I click OK.

However, the next time the modal is displayed, the timer is already near 0 as it did not reset back to 10.

Is there any reason why I cant get this back to 10 seconds?  I thought `clearInterval` should reset the timer?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're never resetting `this.remainingTimeoutSeconds`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought clearInterval should reset the timer?

Do you mean `this.remainingTimeoutSeconds` is set automatically when calling `clearInterval`?

The answer is no.

You need to reset that value as 10000 like blow;

```
handleContinueButtonClick(response) {
  if (response.data.success) {
      console.log("IN")
      this.$bvModal.hide('app-timeout-reminder-modal');
      this.remainingTimeoutSeconds = 10000;
      clearInterval(this.timerId);
      return;
  }
}
```

or

```
showWarningMessage() {
  this.$bvModal.show('timeout-modal');
  this.warning = true;
  this.remainingTimeoutSeconds = 10000;

  this.timerId = setInterval(() => {
    this.remainingTimeoutSeconds -= 1000;
  }, 1000);
}
```